# What is the run-time of inserting the words in a string into a hash table?

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, big-o, hashtable

More info:

- n is the number of characters in the string
- the hash table should keep track of each word's frequency; i.e., the hash table should store key-value pairs, where the key is a word in the input string, and the value is the number of times that word occurs in the input string

We've had some heated debates about this question at work, and I'd like to see what you guys think the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to consider during implementation of insert function is how do we handle collisions and resolution techniques. This will have a greater influence in both put() and get() operations.
The collision resolution techniques are implemented diffently in each libraries. The core idea is to maintain all colliding keys in the same bucket. And during retrieval traverse all the colliding keys and apply some equality check to retrieve the given key. Important thing to note is we need to maintain both 'keys' and 'values' in the bucket, to facilicate the above mentioned equality check.

So the key(words) is also being stored in hash table along with the count.

Another thing to consider is, during insertion operation a hashcode will be generated for the given key. We can consider this to be constant O(1) for every key.

Now, answering the question.
Given a string of length 'n'
Inserting all the words and frequencies will have following steps.

```
1. split given string in to words, with given delimiter - O(n)
2. For word in words                        - O(n)
      # Considering copy of word of length k as constant and very small compared to 'n'. 
      # And collision resolution implementation amortized across all inserts
      if MAP.exists(word)                   - O(1)
          MAP.set(word, MAP.get(word)+1)    - amortized to O(1) 
      else
          MAP.set(word, 1)                  - O(1)
```

Over all, **O(n)** run-time for inserting the words in a string into a hash table. Because the for loop runs 'n/k' times and we know 'k' is constant and small compared to n.

Answer (score 0):

If `H` is your hashtable mapping words to counts, then `H[s]` and `H[s] = <new value>` are both O(len(`s`)). That's because computing the hashcode for `s` requires you to read every character of `s`, and also once you've found the relevant line in the hashtable, you need to compare `s` to whatever's stored there. Of course, the usual hashtable complexities apply to -- there's O(1) of these comparisons performed.

With respect to your original problem, you can break your string of length `n` into words in O(`n`) time. Then for each word, you need an O(len(`word`)) operation to update the hashtable. For all the strings, O(len(`word1`) + len(`word2`) + ... + len(`word_n`)) = O(`n`) overall, since the sum of the length of the words is always less than `n`, the length of the original string.